# Replacing characters in lines of strings

Tags: python, regex

I would like to replace some characters in lines of strings. Three are thousands of these lines in a data frame.

Example of string:

```
(1) W00001 + (0.5) Q00003 <=> (1.7227) U00002 + (4) X21717
```

My code that didn't work:

```
for line in dat:
    line.strip().split("\t")
    line = sub(r'((\.+))',\2, line)
    print line
```

The output that I want:

```
1 W00001 + 0.5 Q00003 <=> 1.7227 U00002 + 4 X21717
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to group using a formatted replacement sting with the format of `\g<group_number>`:

```
>>> s = '(1) W00001 + (0.5) Q00003 <=> (1.7227) U00002 + (4) X21717'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'\(([\d\.]+)\)', '\g<1>', s)
'1 W00001 + 0.5 Q00003 <=> 1.7227 U00002 + 4 X21717'
```

Also, that is probably the regex you want (as I added in the code):

```
\(([\d\.]+)\)
```

Translated to english, it means one char of `(`, group containing one or more digits with possible `.` between, then another closing `)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone for your help. Great solutions! Problem now solved.

Answer (score 2):

Since you just want to remove the parenthesises I suggest to use two `replace()` instead of `regex()`:

```
In [9]: s = '(1) W00001 + (0.5) Q00003 <=> (1.7227) U00002 + (4) X21717'

In [10]: s.replace('(', '').replace(')', '')
Out[10]: '1 W00001 + 0.5 Q00003 <=> 1.7227 U00002 + 4 X21717'
```

Or if you are using python 2.x as a more efficient approach use `str.translate()` method:

```
In [9]: s = '(1) W00001 + (0.5) Q00003 <=> (1.7227) U00002 + (4) X21717'

In [10]: s.translate(None, '()')
Out[10]: '1 W00001 + 0.5 Q00003 <=> 1.7227 U00002 + 4 X21717'
```

In python 3.x:

```
In [18]: import string
In [19]: s = '(1) W00001 + (0.5) Q00003 <=> (1.7227) U00002 + (4) X21717'

In [20]: s.translate(string.maketrans('', ''), '()')
Out[20]: '1 W00001 + 0.5 Q00003 <=> 1.7227 U00002 + 4 X21717'
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove the parenthesis, you can use a simple RegEx:

```
import re

line = "(1) W00001 + (0.5) Q00003 <=> (1.7227) U00002 + (4) X21717"
print(re.sub(r"[()]", "", line))
```

You get:

```
1 W00001 + 0.5 Q00003 <=> 1.7227 U00002 + 4 X21717
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach can be using `split()` and `strip()` functions.

We split our string to get a list of words, then we use `strip` to remove '(' and ')' at the beginning / end of each word, `join()` is then applied to the result to get the desired string.

A generator expression is used to loop over our list of words:

```
s = '(1) W00001 + (0.5) Q00003 <=> (1.7227) U00002 + (4) X21717'
res = ' '.join(item.strip('()') for item in s.split(' '))
print(res)  # Output: 1 W00001 + 0.5 Q00003 <=> 1.7227 U00002 + 4 X21717
```